# Print button in as3 adobe animate

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe-animate

I have two keyframes in the main timeline I want to print when the user clicks a button on frame 1.  I am trying to do this with the code below but although I get the print dialogue to come up it doesn't see to add the pages.  Not sure if I am targeting the right thing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

print_bu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_190);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_190(event:MouseEvent):void
{

```
var myPrintJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

var result:Boolean = myPrintJob.start();

    if (result) {

    this.myPrintJob.addPage(MovieClip(root), null, {printAsBitmap:true}, 2);
    this.myPrintJob.addPage(MovieClip(root), null, {printAsBitmap:true}, 3);
    
    myPrintJob.send();
    
    } else {

        //User does not have printer or user canceled print action

    }
```

}

Comment: I think, first of all you should remove **this** from your script. The **myPrintJob** is a local variable, not a property of the timeline you are on.

Comment: when I remove this I get an error

Comment: Do you have an adobe animate file with a working example of a print button?

Comment: Please, be more specific, what kind of error do you get? And no, I don't have Flash IDE ready.

Comment: I don't get an error I just get the print dialouge pop up but it doesn't add the movie clips to be printed.